No Python executables after colcon build (ament_cmake_python)
So I'm trying to create a ROS Humble Python pkg, but after running colcon build --symlink-install and source install/setup.bash trying to run the script with ros2 run active_reconstruction nbv.py results in a No executable found error.
My file tree looks like this:
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── behaviour_tree
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── behaviours.py
├── include
│   └── active_reconstruction
├── nbv
│   └── __init__.py
├── package.xml
├── scripts
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── behaviour_tree.py
│   └── nbv_node.py
└── src

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(active_reconstruction)

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(ament_cmake_python REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)


# Python --------------------------------------
ament_python_install_package(nbv)

install(PROGRAMS
  scripts/nbv_node.py 
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

ament_python_install_package(behaviour_tree)

install(PROGRAMS
  scripts/behaviour_tree.py
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

ament_package()

And in the package.xml I've specified:
  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>
  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake_python</buildtool_depend>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <exec_depend>rclpy</exec_depend>

I have tried to follow this tutorial, but I can't see what I'm doing different

Make sure that those nodes are defined as executables. You can check this with the command ls -la, this will show you the permissions attached to each file of the current directory, make sure that is recognized as execuable with an x. You can change this using chmod +x <name of executable>

Yup, that is most likey it. Haven't tried it yet, but I remember now I did this once in the past and worked. Totally forgotten about it; Thanks!!

You're welcome, feel free to ask again if that didn't resolve your problem.
